# how to traverse through DOM?

Tags: jquery, click

```
<div class="main-div">                        
   <p class="no-select"><a href="#."><span class="my-icon"></span>Foo1</a></p>
   <p><a href="#.">Foo2</a></p>
   <p><a href="#.">Foo3</a></p>   
   <p><a href="#.">Foo4</a></p>     
</div>
```

This is my DOM structure. What is the better way to write onclick event of

I tried two way:
First by giving each

tag a `unique ID`. and catching those ID `click event`. I think this is weired.

So I tried next way:

```
$("div.main-div > p ").click(function(e) {
    alert('hi');
    return false;
  });
```

But it is not working for me. Where I am wrong..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```
  $("div.main-div > p:not(:first-child)").click(function(e) {
    alert('hi');
    return false;
  });
```

`main-div` is a class not an id